# Different Desktop per workspace

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce, workspaces

I know how to set different desktop wallpaper images per workspace, but I would like to go a step further and have different desktop directories as well, so when I go to 'Project XYZ' workspace I'll see the files and directories I have placed on its desktop and the same with 'Project ABC'. I think such *workspace* is more intuitive and more useful.

Could one somehow pull this off? How?

Comment: More than likely it could be done, but it might take a lot of hacking and scripting to pull it off.  You would have to create a Desktop folder for each workspace you had.  Then you would have to assign each one somehow in your `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.  Then you would have to use wmctrl somehow to call each one when you changed between workspaces.  I have seen some scripting out there but I have not tried it yet as it was kind of hard to read:  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1651769  Some other reports said it was lagging and tough on the CPU.

Comment: I am not sure of such a feature supported in any file manager or environment, which would need to support it, for such feature to work reliably and smoothly.

Comment: Thank you @Terrance. I will try to it working, and if I succeed, I'll add an answer.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour So, did it work? :-)